# Return incoming & outgoing relationships - Cypher - very slow

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have this Cypher query to return the outgoing and incoming relationships of a certain type, for a certain node.

```
MATCH (n)-[r:INPUTWITH]-(m)
WHERE n.personid='12345'
RETURN m.personid, r.relid
LIMIT 5
```

It should be very simple query. However, it takes ~30seconds, for reason I don't understand.

I'm using Neo4J 2.0. I created an index on "personid" like this:

```
Label personLabel = DynamicLabel.label( "Person" );

BatchInserter inserter = inserter.createDeferredSchemaIndex( personLabel ).on( "personid" ).create();
```

Any ideas what's happening???

Comment: You are not using the label index, try `MATCH (n:Person)-[r:INPUTWITH]-(m)` and post back if that makes it any better

Comment: fixed it. Thanks. sorry , such a stupid problem.

Comment: @jjaderberg, that should be an answer.

Comment: @Johan, ok, made an answer of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a label index in a cypher query you must include the label in the query pattern, like so

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[r:INPUTWITH]-(m)
```